# update mongo array with pentaho kettle

Tags: mongodb, kettle

i need to update elements in an array, but could not find a solution. please find details below

this is my table input:

```
select '123' partner_customer_id, '222' order_id, '1' quantity union all
select '123' parner_customer_id, '333' order_id, '2' quantity
```

and this is my mongo output:

```
Name Mongo document path Use field name Match field for upsert Modifier operation Modifier policy
partner_customer_id Y Y N/A Insert
partner_customer_id Y N N/A Insert
order_id sales[0] Y N $set Insert
order_id sales[1] Y N $push Update
quantity sales[0] Y N $set Insert
quantity sales[1] Y N $push Update
```

please find below the screenshot about the mongodb output
http://cl.ly/image/18442w163v1x

When running the above it inserts a customer record with an two element array. (the two orders ) if running it again there will be a customer record with an 4 element array, etc.

But i want to reach that it updates the array elements as well based on the order_id field. eg the quantity changes from 1 to 4 then it updtes the quantity, but array element remains the same only change: quantity is updted in the relevant element. It is possible to do this in pentaho?

thanks in advance